# Mysterious number of chars read with read() in simple chat in C?

Tags: c, sockets, chat

I have coded a simple TCP chat in C language. The server's job is to receive messages from the client and to send them back in reverse order. The result should look like this:

Client: "Hello"

Server: "olleH"

When I apply "strlen()" to "olleH", the returned length is not 5, but 7. 7 is also the value returned by the read() function. What am I missing here? I know that char arrays end with a '\0', but that doesn't explain the 2 extra chars.

The loop should end upon receiving the message "FINISH". So, I compare the received message to the char array "FINISH" using strcmp(). They are never recognized as being the same for the reason exposed above. I am receiving a message with 2 extra chars. I've tried comparing the incoming message to "FINISH__" (interpret '_' as a blank space), but it won't work either.

```
do{

    bzero(buffer, 1000);
    n = read(client_socket, buffer, 1000);
    if (n<0){
        error("ERROR reading socket");
    }

    invert(buffer, inv); //inv is a buffer that stores the inverted array

    n = write(client_socket, inv, n);

    if (n<0){
        error("ERROR writing in socket");
    }

}while (strcmp(buffer, "FINISH\n") != 0);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you handling carriage return `/r` and line feed `/n`? Also, what platform are you using? Linux? Windows?

Comment: I'm running the server on a Linux virtual machine. On the other end I'm using a client written in Java on a Windows platform. As said, when applying "strlen()" to the messages received from the client, strlen() returns a value 2 units larger than the actual length of the message sent from the client.

Comment: OK - make sure the client removes the `Enter` key (CRLF or LF) from the input stream. This could result in the extra characters being sent. Have you printed out the byte stream to see what's actually being received?

Comment: It's never a good idea to simply send data over the network without defining a known data structure, otherwise, how do you know you have read everything that is sent?  Packets get fragmented...   Suggest using the TLC approach.  Create a structure that defines the data type, length and content.  That way you can read your known components (T+L) and then your content (C) based on the type and length already read. Then you can send non-printable characters too.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Inverting the buffer before the `strcmp` at the end of the loop will make you wait how long?

Comment: To ott: yes, that is a flaw in the loop. I'm doing unneeded work if I just received the "FINISH" message. I will certainly solve that problem.

Comment: 'n = read(client_socket, buffer, 1000);' if the full 1000 bytes are rx, the array is not securely null-terminated.  That means that your 'invert' function will almost certainly not work since you do not pass the the number of bytes in the buffer.   Even when less than 1000 bytes are rx, your code can only work for text data, (ie. no embedded nulls).

Comment: 'bzero' is cargo-cult rubbish.  You know how many chars have been rx from the read() result, so you can stick a terminating nul in the buffer using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while sending data from server you must be typing `Hello` then pressing `ENTER` key which is nothing but `\r\n`. So client is reading it as `Hello\r\n`. So you must be getting two characters extra. I hope it works for you. You can check this by looping through input `buffer` and check whether `\r\n` is present over there.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. When I now compare the incoming message with "FINISH\r\n", strcmp() returns 0 (meaning they're equal). Thanks a lot. Stackoverflow never disappoints!

Answer (score 1):

This post might be useful:
[C Socket Write adding extra characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109121/c-socket-write-adding-extra-characters)

When you are receiving 'n' from read it gives you the sizeof the number of bytes read and not the string length of text read.
You are writing 'n' in your write command.
I guess should 'Hello' is of length 5, its of size 7.
This might explain the size 7.
Check what your length is using strlen(buffer) or a equivalent.